# Opencart 1.5.4 with https broken image displayed in Frontend

Tags: php, image, ssl, opencart

For my Opencart project  I have install **SSL**. Site will be access by **HTTPS** but broken images display in front end. In Admin, all the images display with **HTTPS** only problem with front end.

I have set use SSL => YES from setting. Change all URL with HTTPS in config.php

When a try to access the website with HTTPS the images folder is skip from URL.

If I access site with  http Logo URL like :- https://www.domainname.com/image/data/logos/logo.png

If I access site with  https Logo URL like :-
https://www.domainname.com/data/logos/logo.png

Please help me, why the **image** folder skip with HTTPS url?

Comment: Check your htaccess file, it could be that it is ignoring the 'image' folder from https only

Comment: @Sphinx there is no code available in htaccess like that.

Comment: did you change both the config files?

Comment: yes, I have change both the config file

Comment: try and link the image again for one of the products and see if it works for that product

Comment: @Sphinx I tried with this also but its not working.

Comment: see step number 2 below regarding `dir_image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by overwriting the configuration. I don’t know its correct solution or not, but it’s working for me.

I have made the changes in 2 files as below, just added the “image” in the path and its solves

> File /catalog/model/tool/image.php

Line no. 39 & 41

```
return HTTPS_IMAGE . 'image/' . $new_image;

return HTTP_IMAGE . 'image/' . $new_image;
```

> Next file catalog/controller/common/header.php

Line no. 55 & 63

```
$this->data['icon'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon');

$this->data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
```

Comment: This means that the `https_image` paths are incorrect as mentioned below..in your config these paths are not set correctly...edit with the path you are using in your config for `HTTPS_IMAGE` and `HTTP_IMAGE`

Comment: the same path use in Admin and front end. But admin image are display and front end image broken.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first:

1. **Ensure config secure is set to yes in the settings of the store**
2. **Check that the config file is correct in both the root and admin folder**
   The config file should include the `HTTP_SERVER` and the `HTTPS_SERVER` and be setup accordingly. Make sure the `DIR_IMAGE` has the correct path to the images folder in both the config files.
3. **Check the htaccess file for any flaws or redirection**